# Texture Pack Making, Item Sizes in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Do I Make a Custom Texture Pack For Minecraft? (16x16)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23440/how-do-i-make-a-custom-texture-pack-for-minecraft-16x16)

I am going to start making texture packs, as some of my friends have given me ideas for them.  I just need to know if there is any way I can tell how much space (in pixels) I have to make an alternative texture for an item.  Any ideas?

Also: is there any program that I can edit texture packs, so that I can tell what the section I am editing is in the game?

Answer (score 2):

Most basic textures are stored in a single image. You can use any image editor, from Paint to Adobe Photoshop to make your texture pack. Your best bet is to download a [source image](https://minecraft.wiki/w/File:TerrainGuide.png) with labels and draw your texture pack over the top.

Water and lava, as well as mobs require editing other files in the same manner.

[Here's a tutorial](http://minecraftworld.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/how-to-make-a-minecraft-texture-pack/) on how to get started.

Comment: But, that being said, Like how many pixels do I have to make, say, a Gold Sword?

Comment: @CodeAdmiral [The wiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Texture_Packs) details where you can get all the relevant files to make your texture pack. Just open up the relevant file and have a look!

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `%appdata%\.minecraft\bin` on a windows machine and open the .jar file there are all the default texture files, the blocks are in the `terrain.png` image and the items are in `gui\items.png` just edit these (and any thing else you want to reskin) using any image editor and put them in a .zip file in the texture pack folder to use them. The `pack.png` file is the image that appears next to the pack in the menu.