# How do I retexture Minecraft blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am curious how I can retexture my minecaft blocks so it would look better :D

Comment: Are you asking about how to use other people's textures or to create your own?

Comment: If you want to change to color of wool you need to put bone meal on already colored wool. Then recolor it with the dyes that you want.

Comment: This has been asked & answered here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23440/how-do-i-make-a-custom-texture-pack-for-minecraft-16x16

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That depends on the answer to my question - that link doesn't actually give much instruction on simply installing other textures.

Answer (score 1):

You would install a texture pack (or make your own) using the game files.

there is a pretty good library of packs [here](http://www.minecrafttexturepacks.com/)

In the game select texture packs, and then open the folder. From there you would just copy paste the zip of the pack you want to use. then it will show up in the texture pack selection screen(might require game restart).