# How to make resource pack textures for items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm new to this, so please bear with me. I've been trying to make a **resource pack** for a map I'm designing. I've been able to change the block textures, but when I try to change an **item** texture or one of a plant (wheat), it either gives me the pink and black texture error, or an **annoying white block around the item**. 
Usually, If I do clinch the texture, the parts I wish to be transparent are not. I've tried several programs for adding transparency, but they've all returned the classic texture error. I'm really confused as to why. **Can anyone help me understand, then fix it**?

Comment: Related, if not dupe: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23440/how-do-i-make-a-custom-texture-pack-for-minecraft-16x16?rq=1

Comment: Sorry, but it's a resource pack (also containing sounds) and I've got no problem with the texturing of blocks. My problem is specifically with **items**. My apologies if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this will be pretty hard... anyway so, I'm just gonna tell you what **I'd** do.
So first I'd get a copy of the default Minecraft resource pack. Then when you go into the folder just change the textures and such.

Some warnings:
One, Being that some blocks such as grass use special textures, Just drawing all over it will look odd and not look how you want to all the time. (depends on what colour you want it.)

Two, tying to make costume sounds will be very hard. Since 1.7 they changed the way sounds work. However there are ways to fix this, there are some programs that will do this for you. But that is known be a little hard!

Three, When you have **finished** the resource pack remember to put it into *%appdata%/.minecraft/resourcepacks* then select it in game. and start game and test it out!

Oh and if you look hard enough you will find every thing you can change, E.g the image that comes up when you put on a pumpkin, or the look of a enchanted item. (the purple flashy bits.)

Hope this helps somewhat, But if it didn't then... i have my excuses, My first post :3
Oh and i was just tying to say everything that might help. since as i don't know how good you are at it at all so i just acted like you needed to know!

Comment: Thank you Mr. Rielight! I actually figured out how to do it with your tips. Adding custom sounds is not that hard. Here is a video link if you ever need to do it.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jXLhhiaKWQ

Comment: @JackHarkness if the information in the answer solved your problem, then you should click the checkmark under the score to indicate you've accepted it.  It gives rep to the answerer, shows others the post was useful, and gives you a bit of rep too.

Comment: @JackHarkness No problem! :D

Answer (score -1):

The site that I use for texture editing is http://minecraft.novaskin.me/texturepacks  it is very in editing textures of items and its very simple to use!

Hope this helps! =)